# How can I tell which version of sakila database i am using?

Tags: mysql

the `MySQL` `Sakila` documentation suggests that authors tell students which version of the database they are using: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-authors-note.html

I am using the demo site: https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/structure&server=2&db=sakila

Can I use a `SELECT` statement to find the version of the database? When I run `SELECT version();` I get `8.0.3-rc-log`, which i believe is the version of `innoDB`. But I don't think that's the `sakila` version as the latest appears to be `1.1` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-news-1.1.html)

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT version();` returns the version of MySQL Server (which is 8.0.3 in your case)

Comment: Well, you're wrong sir Madhur: `SELECT @@innodb_version`. Every plugin has its version. @emma how about: `show VARIABLES where Variable_name like '%sakila%'`